# In-app billing monthly subscription showing per day

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I added in app billing in my app. Test billing works fine, but the payment shows per day instead of per month. I created subscription for month in play store.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25YYA.png)

Please help me I am not able to find the issue.

Comment: "but the payment shows per day instead of per month" what does this mean?

Comment: Actually I created monthly subscription in play store. But the subscription is showing 0.99/ day instead of  0.99/month.Please check the attached image

Comment: It's weird. Try to clean Google Play Services cache from the device.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found it if the user email is added as test user in play store it will not show the actual value. To check the subscription use the email that is not added as test user in play store.